# Google Glass BarcodeEye app does not scan 1-D Barcodes

Tags: barcode, google-glass

I try to scan 1-D barcodes (EAN) with the BarcodeEye app (based on XZing) for Google Glass. It scans QR codes very well, but fails to recognize EAN barcodes on any of the food packages in my kitchen. I tried holding the bar codes at ranges from 10cm to 50cm and various in between. The scanning window shows up fine, with the red horizontal line. One or two yellow dots sometimes appear on the red line. But the bar code does not get recognized. At close range (about 10cm) the image looks blurred.

Does anyone else have the same experience, that 1-D barcodes do not work in BarcodeEye? Are there any things to tweak in the app? (I know Java and Android development, I would just need some hints)

I loaded the BarcodeEye app onto my Glass using Eclipse (ADT bundle), by compiling the code and running it on my Glass.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a similar report: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zxing/P-QLWhlB_wU/hxg8h-Pj-jAJ

Comment: It seems that for now the Glass camera only supports focus distance "indefinite", and therefore does not recognize small and nearby barcodes, only blown-up barcodes (< 4 inches) further away. See https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=303.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use the BarCodeEye project as library in my application. I also want to scan QR code but I find it difficult to use BarCodeEye.